# rails, how to pass self in function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, self

message and user. my message belongs_to user and user has_many messages.

in one of my views, i call something like

```
current_user.home_messages?
```

and in my user model, i have...

```
  def home_messages?
    Message.any_messages_for
  end
```

and lastly in my message model, i have

```
scope :any_messages_for

    def self.any_messages_for
        Message.where("to_id = ?", self.id).exists? 
    end
```

ive been trying to get the current_users id in my message model. i could pass in current_user as a parameter from my view on top but since im doing

```
current_user.home_messages?
```

i thought it would be better if i used self. but how do i go about referring to it correctly?

thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a lambda. In your Message model:

```
scope :any_messages_for, lambda {|user| where('user_id = ?', user.id)}
```

This would work like so:

```
Message.any_messages_for(current_user)
```

And you could add a method to your user model to return true if any messages are found. In this case you use an instance method and pass in the instance as self:

```
def home_messages?
  return true if Message.any_messages_for(self)
end
```

But really, I'd just do something like this in the User model without having to write any of the above. This uses a Rails method that is created when declaring :has_many and :belongs_to associations:

```
def home_messages?
  return true if self.messages.any?
end
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I should note that you don't need the 'return true if' part in the last method. You could just write self.messages.any?

Answer (score 2):

You can do either of the following

```
def self.any_messages_for(id) #This is a class method
    Message.where("to_id = ?", id).exists? 
end
```

to call above method you have to do

```
User.any_messages_for(current_user.id) #I am assuming any_messages_for is in `User` Model
```

OR

```
def any_messages_for #This is a instance method
    Message.where("to_id = ?", self.id).exists? 
end
```

to call above method you have to do

```
current_user.any_messages_for
```

Comment: I personally prefer second one....also according to ruby method naming convention, you should put `?` in front of your method which returns true/false.In your case method name should be something like `any_messages_for?` OR `has_any_message?`

Answer (score 1):

This stuff in your Message class doesn't make a lot of sense:

```
scope :any_messages_for

def self.any_messages_for
    Message.where("to_id = ?", self.id).exists? 
end
```

The `scope` macro defines a class method on its own and there should be another argument to it as well; also, scopes are meant to define, more or less, a canned set of query parameters so your `any_messages_for` method isn't very scopeish; I think you should get rid of `scope :any_messages_for`.

In your `any_messages_for` class method, `self` will be the class itself so `self.id` won't be a user ID and so it won't be useful as a placeholder value in your `where`.

You should have something more like this in Message:

```
def self.any_messages_for(user)
  where('to_id = ?', user.id).exists?
  # or exists?(:to_id => user.id)
end
```

And then in User:

def home_messages?
    Message.any_messages_for(self)
  end

Once all that's sorted out, you can say `current_user.home_messages?`.